# Doe Traefik support latency balancing?

Tags: load-balancing, traefik

On of the simplest and also most performant ways of balancing load over multiple targets is using latency balancing. A great animated way of showing various load balance techniques is [here](https://samwho.dev/load-balancing/)

Therefore a bit dumbfounded that I can't find a single mention about Latency loadbalancing in [Traefik](https://traefik.io/)

Did I mis something, or is this available as a supported plugin for example? The mentioned round-robin and weighted round-robin strategies don't cut it for me sadly.

Comment: It only supports round-robin: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/services/#weighted-round-robin-service